# swap ng-repeat list with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am creating project using angularjs. I want to swap one field of data using drag and drop. Here is my code:

```
 <div class="rTableRow" ng-repeat="interfaceData in interfaces | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort|filter:{id:viewVnf.bus,mac:viewVnf.macAddr,flowid:viewVnf.flowId}" drag-to-reorder="interfaces">
     <div class="rTableCell table_col_1">{{interfaceData.id}}</div>
     <div class="rTableCell table_col_2">{{interfaceData.mac}}</div>
     <div class="rTableCell table_col_3">{{interfaceData.flowid}}</div>
 </div>
```

I am using `drag-to-reorder` this directive but this will only reorder the whole repeat but in mu case i want to swap only flow id (not reorder).

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this need to create the custom directive:

Here is the

```
plunkar: `http://plnkr.co/iy63pZ`
```